# iCloud - two songs, same album - one Matched, one Ineligible. How to fix?

Tags: icloud, itunes-match

I have 250 songs marked Ineligible, and I can't figure out why.  They are all 128kbps or greater, way less than 200MB, all Protected AAC audio files purchased by my ex.  I am authorized on his account and can play the songs in iTunes just fine.  In most cases only one or two songs from an album were rejected, while the rest were Matched, though some entire albums were rejected.

The advice online for fixing this centers around telling iTunes to convert the file to AAC, but in this case it gives an error that protected files can't be converted to other formats.  It seems most people with this error have low bit rate files, but that is not the case this time.

Is there anything I can do to fix this short of getting the unprotected files from him (which he would be fine with, but it could be years before he gets around to doing it)?

Comment: I tried burning the song to an audio CD, then importing.  This worked, but it messes up the album.  To make things right, I had to first go in and rename the file (iTunes had imported it starting with 01 instead of the correct track number of 19), then fix the track number in iTunes, then fix all the rest of the album to know it had 18 tracks (I had deleted the original file, which resent all the track counts). In short, this works but is not ideal.

The file should have matched in the first place;  there wasn't anything wrong with it.  It would be way better to figure out the root problem.